# CSS for elements that have certain children elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Lets say I have this html

```
<div class="house"><span class="zombie"/></div>
<div class="house"><span class="vampire"/></div>
<div class="house"><span class="zombie"/></div>
```

How could I write a bit of CSS to target "div .house" that only has children with "span .vampire"? And "div .house" might not always be the direct parent of "span .zombie"

Comment: Possibly of interest: [Why we don't have a parent selector](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors)

Comment: :has() is not so "cascading", is reverse-cascading xD

Answer (score 1):

You can't. This is the one thing that CSS can't do.

jQuery has the [`:has()` pseudo-selector.](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

Comment: CW'ing because this is of course a dupe. Thanks @BoltClock

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with CSS alone. You can however quite easily with jQuery.

```
$('.house:has(.vampire)').doStuff();
```

or

```
$('.house').has('.vampire').doStuff();
```